# Probability function for the smaller of two dice scores

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A fair die is rolled twice. Let $X$ be the smaller of the two scores. I must determine the probability function of $X$.

My main worry with this problem (apart from me being completely new to studying statistics) is actually interpreting it. My interpretation of "smaller of the two scores" implies that if the same number is rolled twice, then a smaller number cannot be chosen from the two, as they are both equal. Is this a logical interpretation?

If so, my probability function looks like this: $$f_{X}(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{10}{36}&x=1\\\frac{8}{36}&x=2\\\frac{6}{36}&x=3\\\frac{4}{36}&x=4\\\frac{2}{36}&x=5\\\frac{6}{36}&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
But I don't like that. Something tells me that "otherwise" should be $0$ (namely that $X$ takes values in $S=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, if my interpretation is right) but there is still the chance that two of the same values are rolled one after the other. How does one account for this?

I understand this is most likely a trivial question, so many thanks for your hints, help and patience in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That "otherwise" should be $\frac{1}{36}$, in order to represent the only case where the smallest value is $6$.

By the way, your PDF is wrong, here is the correct one:

$
  P(X=n)=
   \begin{cases}
    \frac{11}{36}&n=1\\\
    \frac{ 9}{36}&n=2\\\
    \frac{ 7}{36}&n=3\\\
    \frac{ 5}{36}&n=4\\\
    \frac{ 3}{36}&n=5\\\
    \frac{ 1}{36}&n=6\\\
  \end{cases}
$

Or simply $P(X=n)=\frac{13-2n}{36}$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm still just a tad confused though. My PDF does sum to 1. I originally had the PDF you've given me above, but then I thought, what if I rolled a (1,1), a (2,2), a (3,3), etc.?

Comment: @MathNoob: Sorry, you're right about the "sums up to $1$". Nevertheless, your PDF is still wrong. So what if you rolled $(1,1)$? There are still $11$ cases where $1$ is the smaller value. You can simply count them and see for yourself (and then do the same for each of the other values).

Comment: So is my interpretation wrong? That is, if I roll two of the same numbers in a row, do I take that value for the "smaller of the two"?

Comment: @MathNoob: Well, second thought, perhaps my interpretation is wrong, and all equal cases should be accounted for as "otherwise", exactly as you wrote it. But that would be rather unusual for this type of questions. My interpretation is simply "smallest". Your interpretation is "smaller", and you're in fact correct about $1$ not being smaller than $1$ (for example). I will therefore remove my answer once you've read this comment.

Comment: Don't remove it. It has been helpful. Thank you for your time. I will think more on this. The question was presented to me just as you see it above and I must say, it could be more clear!

Comment: Turns out your interpretation is correct, after doing some study! Thank you once again.

Comment: @MathNoob: You're welcome :)